# Concatenate two strings, 'present working directory' and the 'app.exe' filename to frame absolute path

Tags: batch-file, string-concatenation

I have a directory structure similar to this:

under `'D:\Ashwin\rev'`

```
rev
-->dist
---->app.exe
-->copier
---->cs
------>cs.bat
------>pscp.exe
-->Copy.bat
```

Content of `Copy.bat` is:

```
@echo "Starting copy"
@call "copier\cs\cs.bat"
```

and content of `cs.bat` is incomplete yet.

```
%BINARY% = DIR /b dist\*%.exe
%ASH% = %CD%%1\dist\%BINARY% 

@call copier\cs\pscp -l root -pw ReDBuLL <What to do?> 192.168.1.16:/root/workspace
```

Here's why. I am totally new to batch script. 
The purpose of this script is to send the .exe file alone to the remote server using [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
tool.

I am stuck concatenating the two strings.

1. `BINARY` which has the `app.exe` name.
2. `ASH` which is the concatenated
   string of current working path and `BINARY`

With this concatenated sting I plan to pass this to the `pscp` command and transfer the file to the remote server.

I should only be using `Copy.bat` to copy the file and not the `cs.bat`

What else is missing here?

P.S: I could have hard coded the path but that's not what I am looking to do. Because app.exe would not be the only file in the directory as I am going to add several other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your code is from a linux script, but in the windows world this doesn't work this way.
Don't use spaces for formatting your code (like in `%BINARY% = DIR /b dist\*%.exe`), it changes the behaviour!
Binary and also ASH aren't set to the output of the commands, the content is the command.

To get the output of a command you normally use the `FOR/F-Loop` construct.

`for /f "delims=" %%A in ('DIR /b dist\*.exe') DO set "binary=%%A"`

So your code would like more like this

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('DIR /b dist\*.exe') Do set "binary=%%A"
set "ASH=%CD%\dist\%BINARY%"

set "PastedString=%ASH%\%BINARY%"
echo The content of PastedString is %PastedString%
call copier\cs\pscp -l root -pw ReDBuLL "%PastedString%" 192.168.1.16:/root/workspace
```

Comment: How would I output "PastedString" variable?

Comment: @Ashwin kumar - I added it (`echo %PastedString%`) to the code

Comment: It does not output anything on my Windows 7 console.. Any thoughts? :-)

Comment: It should output an error message as I forgot the `DO` :-(  I will edit my answer

Comment: Firstly, for /f "delims=" %%A in ('DIR /b dist\*%.exe') set "binary=%%A" Never works.. Anything beyond the line just fails. Secondly, Sorry for updating late

Comment: I did include the 'DO' which you hadn't include your edit previously. Still, it did not work. I will try it out again once on my workstation. :-)

Comment: Ok, I removed the percent sign in `DIR /b dist*%`

Comment: Works now!! Wonderful. Pls change in the sample code too.. it could help someone like me.. :-)